# R: plot3D scatter3D, is there a coord_fixed() option?

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, scatter-plot, plot3d

I am doing the same scatter plots in 2D and 3D with `ggplot2` and `plot3d`. I always like to do `coord_fixed()` in `ggplot2` scatter plots when possible, for better readability. Is there a way to do the same in the `scatter3D` plot?

MWE:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point(pch=16) + theme_light() + coord_fixed()
library(plot3D)
scatter3D(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, bty = "u", pch = 16, alpha = 0.5,
          xlab = "Petal.Length", ylab = "Sepal.Length", zlab = "Petal.Width", phi = 0, theta = 40,
          col.panel = "white", col.grid = "gray", col="black", ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale = FALSE` does this:

```
scatter3D(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, bty = "u", pch = 16, alpha = 0.5,
          xlab = "Petal.Length", ylab = "Sepal.Length", zlab = "Petal.Width", phi = 0, theta = 40,
          col.panel = "white", col.grid = "gray", col="black", ticktype = "detailed",
          scale = FALSE)
```

From `?persp`:

> If scale is TRUE the x, y and z coordinates are transformed separately. If scale is FALSE the coordinates are scaled so that aspect ratios are retained